# Code not executing in order (Firebase). Synchronization issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
const signIn = async e => {
      var recaptcha = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha');
      var number = '+91'+mobile;
      firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(number, recaptcha).then( function(e) {
      var code = prompt('Enter the otp', '');
      if(code === null) 
      {
        return false;
      }

         e.confirm(code).then(function (result) {
             console.log(result.user);

             alert("INSIDE");
             return true;

         }).catch(function (error) {
             console.error( error);

         });

     })
     .catch(function (error) {
         console.error( error);
         return false;
     });
  }
```

And the other function

```
const func1 = async e => {
alert("OUTSIDE1");
var check=await signIn();
if(check)
{
   alert("true value");
}
else
{
   alert("false value");
}
```

The output is always-

OUTPUT1

false value

and then the OTP code gets executed?
Can someone help to make the necessary changes to make OTP code synchronous?

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning an appropriate promise to the caller of your async function.  You probably meant to write:

```
return firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(...).then(...)
```

Even better, since you are using async/await, just await the result of `signInWithPhoneNumber` inside your `signIn` function, and avoid the use of `then()/catch()` entirely.

Comment: "Even better, since you are using async/await, just await the result of signInWithPhoneNumber inside your signIn function, and avoid the use of then()/catch() entirely."- can you please give the syntax for this? Also if I use this what will be the value in variable check?

Comment: i am getting check as undefined

Comment: There are resources you can find using a web search that will help you learn async/await syntax.

Comment: Sir I have been struggling with this code for quite some time now. I have tried both- return firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(number, recaptcha).then( function(e) and await firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(number, recaptcha).then( function(e) . check is coming out to be undefined